# How to introduce xgboost in pyscript

Tags: xgboost

I found that the xgboost package exists in pyodide, but I can't import it in the  of pyscript

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  <py-env>
    - numpy
    - matplotlib
    - pandas
    - scikit-learn
    - xgboost

  </py-env>
```

error:
ValueError: Couldn't find a pure Python 3 wheel for 'xgboost'. You can use `micropip.install(..., keep_going=True)` to get a list of all packages with missing wheels.

Answer (score 0):

As for "I found that the xgboost package exists in pyodide,", I think you mean to reference the announcement [here](https://blog.pyodide.org/posts/0.21-release/) of Pyodide 0.21.0. However, as Pyscript is built on top of Pyodide, it doesn't mean as a Pyscript user you immediately reap the benefits of an update to Pyodide.

I believe [this discussion](https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/pyodide-version-used-with-pyscript/33271) relates to your question and the code in [the linked twitter thread](https://twitter.com/tunguz/status/1565086536076595201) shows you how you could use the 'unstable' release now.